# Splitting a list into n-sized chunks

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a function that splits a list into n-sized chunks.

For example a function like this: `fun([1,2,3,4], 3)` should output `[[1,2,3],[2,3,4]]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want or not, but I would recommend:

```py
def split_list(list, n):
    toReturn = []
    for i in range(len(list)//n):
        toReturn.append(list[i*n:i*n+n])
    toReturn.append(list[-n:])
    return toReturn
```